# How do you pass an array to a function like this: void fooboo(char array[i]);

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameter-passing, function-calls

I am trying to understand exactly what this code is trying to accomplish. The function median was given, but I added the main function and typedef/prototypes in efforts to comprehend what it does, by passing something into the function. However I can figure out what or how to pass something to it. I understand that the function is some kind of sort. What I really need to know is what is exactly being passed to the function? An array of N index?

Thank you for any guidance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char pix_t;
pix_t median(pix_t window[N]);

int main() {

    pix_t window[] = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    pix_t output;
    output = median(window[N]);

}

pix_t median(pix_t window[N])
{
    pix_t t[N], z[N];
    int ii, k, stage;

    // copy locally
    for (ii = 0; ii<N; ii++) z[ii] = window[ii];

    for (stage = 1; stage <= N; stage++) {
        k = (stage % 2 == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        for (ii = k; ii<N - 1; ii++) {
            t[ii] = MIN(z[ii], z[ii + 1]);
            t[ii + 1] = MAX(z[ii], z[ii + 1]);
            z[ii] = t[ii];
            z[ii + 1] = t[ii + 1];
        }
    }

    return z[N / 2];
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm just missing it, but where is `N` defined? Doesn't seem it'd even compile.

Comment: Also, the `median` function is expecting an array of `pix_t`, but you're sending a single scalar value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the function signature

```
pix_t median(pix_t window[N])
```

a call like

```
median(window[N]);
```

is wrong. The function expects an array of `pix_t` with at least `N` elements <sup>**Note**</sup>, whereas, you're passing only a single variable of type `pix_t`.

*Morale of the story:: Whenever in confusion, check the data types*

The function should be called with an array, something like

```
#define N 10                                    //any number

int main(void) {                               //note the change

    pix_t window[N] = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    pix_t output;
    output = median(window);                   //passing the array
}
```

should do.

---

Point to note: despite the array notation used in the function signature

```
 pix_t median(pix_t window[N]) { //....
```

inside the function, `window` is not an *array*. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.3

> A declaration of a parameter as *‘‘array of type’’* shall be adjusted to *‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’*, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. [....]

---

Note:

> *What I really need to know is what is exactly being passed to the function? An array of `N` index?*

The meaning of "at least N elements" refers to the a guarantee that the array has enough storage space to hold `N` elements up to position `N-1`, not that indices `N`, `N+1`, `N+2`, `...` are valid/addressable.

You can read it as: "I have a guarantee of at *least* `N` cells of storage space so that I can store at *most* `N` elements in `N-1` valid positions."

However, it's the programmer's responsibility to keep track of these details manually to avoid indexing into an invalid location and causing a segmentation fault; the environment will not do this automatically for you.

Comment: "The function expects an array of pix_t with at least N elements". This looks incorrect. It's with at *most* `N-1` elements; "at least" then it implies you can index `N`, `N+1`, etc., which would simply segfault.

Comment: @ray I'm not sure. I read it like, "it is guaranteed that the pointer would allow at least `N-1` valid indexes ", though this is enforced by the programmer, not by standard.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but you could at least clarify that the "at least" is meant as a guarantee of the indexable space, not as in "at least `X-1`, so can safely index into `X`, `X+1`, etc"

Comment: @ray Sure thing, I tried elaborating, still if you feel it can be clarified in a better way, feel free to edit, and thank you.

Comment: I edited the last paragraph b/c saying that there's a programmer's "guarantee" for addressable indices to then say that it's not "guaranteed" by the environment seems somewhat contradictory. Hope the rewording works for you.

Comment: @ray Sure, appreciate that!!

Comment: I would like to say thank you for your detailed comments. I am new to programming in C and I feel like this post has helped me significantly. Take care :)

Answer (score 5):

With `window[N]` you pass a *single element* to the function. The element with index `N`. Which, depending on the value of `N` might be out of bounds.

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, and functions declared to take an array as argument in reality takes a pointer. That means you can use just the array name and it will work:

```
median(window);
```